# jQuery Validate not firing submitHandler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="/home/keepintouch" id="stay-in-touch">
              <div>
                <label for="email">Stay in touch</label>
                <input type="text" value="enter your email address" title="Keep up-to-date with new products, services, news and special offers." size="20" name="email" id="email" class="off field required email">
                <input type="image" src="/content/images/contact-arrow.png" name="intouch-submit" class="imgbtn">
              </div>
            </form>
```

In my page I'm including the following JS files:

And in my script file I do this:

```
// contact form.
$('#stay-in-touch').validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function (response, status, xhr, form) {
                $('#stay-in-touch div').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $('#stay-in-touch').append('<div class="msg">' + response.msg + '</div>');
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

But the submitHandler doesn't fire.

Any ideas?

I've tried placing an ALERT(..) inside the submitHandler but no joy. The code to map validation is definitely running.

You can see the live code here:

http://www.energyjump.co.uk/

Comment: .ajaxsubmit() is a form plugin.. have you added that to your html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need an `<input type="submit"` , not just a regular button/ image.

Answer (score 1):

its working . when you enter correct email click on the link it displaying the alert.

The submitHandler works only after validations are ok. Please check it.

If you want to show error message or something try to do it in highlight or unhighlight properties