# Jquery Validation submitHandler Not Working from Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

Ok - I have a modal dialog form using a jquery-ui modal dialog, and the dialog buttons are supposed to submit the form.

When the Add Utility button is clicked, the form.submit action is called, but neither the invalidHandler, submitHandler, or notNone methods are ever called.  The form is also never submitted to the webservice, so its not like it is just skipping over the validation portion.

Any help to figure out why the validation isn't running would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.validator.addMethod('notNone', 
                          function (value, element) { return (value != 'none');}, 
                          'Please select an option.');
    $("#modal-form-addUtility").validate({
        errorContainer: "#errorblock-div1, #errorblock-div2",
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorblock-div2 ul",
        wrapper: "li",
        rules: {
             utilitySelectComboBox: {
                notNone: true
            }
        },
        invalidHandler: submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("Invalid");
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("Submitted");
        }
    });
     $('#AddUtility').click(function () {
        $("#AddUtilityDialog").dialog("open");
    });
     $("#AddUtilityDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,

        buttons: {
            "Add Utility": function () { $("#modal-form-addUtility").submit(); },
            Cancel: function () {
                $("#modal-form-addUtility").resetForm();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="button" id="AddUtility" name="AddUtility" value="Add"/>
<div id="AddUtilityDialog" class="ui-widget" title="Add New Utility">
    <div class="ui-widget ui-helper-hidden" id="errorblock-div1">
        <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0pt 0.7em;" id="errorblock-div2" style="display:none;"> 
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: 0.3em;"></span> 
                         <strong>Alert:</strong> Errors detected!</p>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form action="/TextManager.svc/AddUtility" name="modal-form-addUtility" id="modal-form-addUtility" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Select Utility </label>
            <select id="utilitySelectComboBox">   
                <option value="none">Select one...</option>
                <option value="5506">PEE DEE Electric - 5506</option>
                <option value="5505">Mower County Electric - 5505</option>    
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate not firing submitHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213772/jquery-validate-not-firing-submithandler)